# Construct a differentiable and periodic function

Tags: functions, derivatives, periodic-functions

I am looking for a **differentiable and periodic** function $f$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

$1)$ $f(x_i) = y_i,~ $ for given $x_i,y_i$, $ \forall i \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$;

$2)$ $f(x_{i+kn}) = f(x_i), ~ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$;

$3)$ $ x_{j} - x_{j-1} = \Delta x~ (constant),~\forall j \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Is there some method to construct a such function?

I appreciate some hints/references to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are infinitelly many functions that satisfy your conditions. You will need to be much more specific to get any sort of good answer.

Comment: Maybe Fourier series can be a good start. Anyway, I think (99% sure) that 5xum is right, there can be infinite solutions to your problem.

Comment: @5xum  What is the matter if there are infinitely many solutions? I am asking how to construct a (not "the") differentiable and periodic function satisfying the three conditions.

Comment: @the_candyman, I just want to construct a such function (no problem if there are infinetly many solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the number of points $n$ is **odd**. For example, consider $x_0 = -2$, $x_1 = -1$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$ and $x_4 = 2$, and $y_0 = 4$, $y_1 = 2, y_2 = 1, y_3 = -1$ and $y_4 = -2$ ($n=5$).

In this case $\Delta x = 1$, while the period is $T = n\Delta x = 5.$

You can try to find your function using a truncated Fourier series of order $m = \frac{n-1}{2}:$

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(a_k \cos\left(\frac{2\pi xk}{T}\right) + b_k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi xk}{T}\right)\right). $$

In your case, $m=2$, and you have to find the parameters $a_0$, $a_1$,$a_2$, $b_1$ and $b_2$. They are $5$, which is the same number of available points $n$. This is very important.

Now, you can substitute the available points to the function $f$:

$$\begin{cases}
f(x_0) = y_0 \\
f(x_1) = y_1 \\
f(x_2) = y_2 \\
f(x_3) = y_3 \\
f(x_4) = y_4
\end{cases} \Rightarrow\\
\begin{cases}
\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(a_k \cos\left(\frac{-4\pi k}{5}\right) + b_k \sin\left(-\frac{4\pi k}{5}\right)\right) = 4\\
\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(a_k \cos\left(\frac{-2\pi k}{5}\right) + b_k \sin\left(-\frac{2\pi k}{5}\right)\right) = 2\\
\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(a_k \cos\left(0\right) + b_k \sin\left(0\right)\right) = 1\\
\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(a_k \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{5}\right) + b_k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{5}\right)\right) = -1\\
\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(a_k \cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}{5}\right) + b_k \sin\left(\frac{4\pi k}{5}\right)\right) = -2\\
\end{cases}.$$

This system can be rewritten in matricial form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \cos\left(-\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & \cos\left(-\frac{8\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(-\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(-\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)\\
\frac{1}{2} & \cos\left(-\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) & \cos\left(-\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(-\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(-\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)\\
\frac{1}{2} & \cos\left(0\right) & \cos\left(0\right) & \sin\left(0\right) & \sin\left(0\right)\\
\frac{1}{2} & \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)\\
\frac{1}{2} & \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{8\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
a_2\\
b_1\\
b_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
2 \\
1\\
-1\\
-2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If the matrix is invertible, then you are done!

In this case, I get the following:

$$  a_0 \simeq 1.6, a_1 \simeq  -0.1236,
    a_2 \simeq 0.32,
   b_1 \simeq  -2.5520,
    b_2 \simeq 1.5772.$$

Here is how this function looks like:
[image]
**Addition** The number of points must be odd, since the number of parameters of the truncated Fourier series is odd too. In order to have a well posed system of equation, you need to have as many unknowns (the parameters) as the available data, as well as the same number of equations.

For more details on Fourier series, [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It really did help me! :)

Comment: @AlexSilva you are welcome!